# Using a dropdown menu to select which page to go to next

Tags: php, html

I am currently making a basic 'system' to automaticly generate a email signature with the input a user gives, so first/last name, email adres and job title.
Now we have three differente co-organizations with different names and logos.
So i want to have a dropdown menu that depending on your choice redirects you
to the respective page, those three option all have different logo's/adresses.

I have 1 page working but that is without the dropdown menu, i got the menu in place, this is my code:

```
  <td>School:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="Which school?">
    <option>opt 1</option>
    <option>opt 2</option>
    <option>opt 3</option>
    <option>opt 4</option>
    </select>
```

I am using HTML in a PHP file, i have scavenged all pieces of code from the internet and some from my own knowledge.

How do i go about doing this? I've searched google a bit and found out that it might need a if/else statement or something with javascript?

If anyone is able to help me, that would be great!

Regards,
Luke

Comment: So you want to change the page depending on the option chosen by the user? Do you want this to happen when someone selects a option or when someone clicks a button?

Comment: He or she selects the option, then clicks a button.

Comment: Please make your question clearer. On what exactly you want and include the error if you have.

Comment: I do not have anything code wise yet, i do have the basic functionality, when you fill everything in and click next it generates it nicely in a layout.
Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/Bm9PUNLZ

Comment: Looking at your full code, you are already sending all data into the URL, why not create an if statement so you can adjust the content of the email with the school provided by the user?

Comment: Hi Granny, how do i got about doing that?

Comment: @luukwa, in the awnser i deleted i was using Javascript but you can do this with PHP aswell, When you submit the form it sends all data (except the selectbox value) to hand.php, in this file you can retrieve the data from the url and create an if statement to adjust the email content for each school. This is not that hard so i suggest you start reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411836/read-value-from-url-in-php). You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737981/php-get-select-option-value) post to put the selectbox value into the url aswell

Comment: @Luukwa If you need help creating this file i suggest we connect on discord or something similar (I am dutch aswell so no english needed either)

Comment: @Granny Could you send me your discord over a private message?

Comment: @Luukwa JNjmdX This is the code for my server, i dont use it so there isnt much happening. Im not sure if im allowed to share a link and i dont have the abitlity to private message you.

Comment: @Granny Hmm, why not add my directly? My ID is: Luukwa#7688

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a lot of things here.
Review forms: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
Review select: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp
Then for PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp
PHP forms: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Your form declares an action.  The action is just the page where the selection of your user will be sent.  In that action page, do an if (or switch for multiple values) to decide which page to send the user.  Once that is decided, use this javascript call to redirect the user to the desired page:

```
header('Location: http://school_for_your_student.com/');
```

Note that the header must be the *only output to the client*.  Do not do a print of something and then use header.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I made a few tweaks and got the select thing to work.
But since i use _post and _get the next page doesnt know the variables so it cand load them, so i get a bunch of 
Notice: Undefined index:  errors.

Comment: In your form tag, you must specify either method="POST" or method="GET".  Then in your action page, you use $_POST or $_GET accordingly to access values.

Comment: I figured, but since the second page has no idead that the variabled exist.. how would i fix that?

Comment: Sorry I can't give a PHP course in 600 chars.  But at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp  you have a full working example of a form and what code to put in the action page to access the variables.  Try it out, and post another specific question with what you tried.